# Using iconv to convert utf-8 characters to the closest ASCII character

Tags: unicode, conversion, ascii

I can use the `iconv` command to "translit" a utf-8 string to an ASCII-only string with characters being replaced with their closest ASCII character. However, my problem is that I need the resulting string to contain **exactly the same number of characters** (code points) as the source string. For example the British pound (`£`) character is being replaced with three characters (`GBP`) or the character `æ` with the two characters `ae`. Instead, I want these characters to be replaced with a *single* character (for example, `L` or `?` or `a` or `e`). Is there a method / option for this?

---

## Overview

I am trying to develop an "ASCII-based" find routine for Latin-based text. For example, `find 'uco' in '£Húçôz'` should return position 3 (I am counting from 1 for the first position) and not 5 (because`£` is expanded to 3 characters and not one). Please, note that, what I am trying to develop is much more complex; I have tried to simplify my question as much as possible here.

Also note that, this *find* routine need not be perfect in matching non-ASCII Latin-based text strings, but the (first) position of the match (if there is one) should point to the correct character (code point) position.

Comment: It seams more like grep than find. Some sort of close-ish match.

Comment: I think the bit of terminology you're seeking is "(extended) grapheme cluster".

Comment: Searching like this is honestly very hard and you'll need to make a lot of decisions about what you consider "equivalent", but normalization form NFKC is probably also helpful. I don't think there's going to be a useful generic flattening.

Comment: I was also thinking about the idea of combining characters. Unicode knows that ä can be made by combining a combiling-" and an a. So it could know that an ä is related to an a. However doing this for the whole unicode will be a MASSIVE project. If you are doing it for just European languages, then it is probably do-able.

Comment: That is the reason I am resorting to the `iconv` routine. It does a good job with the `TRANSLIT` option. The only problem is in the number of ASCII characters it returns. Returning a single `?` will be acceptable for any problematic (for example non-"Latin-like") character.